# Divide floats in awk

Tags: awk, floating-point, division

I have written a code to calculate the zscore which calculates the mean and standard deviation from one file and uses some values from rows in another file, as follows:

```
 mean=$(awk '{total += $2; count++} END {print total/count}' ABC_avg.txt)
#calculating mean of the second column of the file
std=$(awk '{x[NR]=$2; s+=$2; n++} END{a=s/n; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/n); print sd}' ABC_avg.txt)
#calculating standard deviation from the second column of the same file
awk '{if (std) print $2-$mean/$std}' ABC_splicedavg.txt" > ABC.tmp
#calculate the zscore for each row and store it in a temporary file
zscore=$(awk '{total += $0; count++} END {if (count) print total/count}' ABC.tmp)
#calculate an average of all the zscores in the rows and store it in a variable 
echo $motif"  "$zscore
rm ABC.tmp
```

However when I execute this code ,at the step where a temp file is created I get an error as **fatal: division by zero attempted**, what is the right way to implement this code? TIA I used bc -l option but it gives a very long version of the floating integer.

Comment: bash variables are not visible within `awk` single quotes.  You have to define them with `-v` option.  However, better is redesign so that all are computed in the same script so that you don't need to pass variables between scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script to compute mean and std in one pass, you may lose some resolution if not acceptable there are alternatives...

```
$ awk '{print rand()}' <(seq 100) 
  | awk '{sum+=$1; sqsum+=$1^2}
      END{print mean=sum/NR, std=sqrt(sqsum/NR-mean^2), z=mean/std}' 

0.486904 0.321789 1.51312
```

Your script for z-score for each sample is wrong!  You need to do ($2-mean)/std.

Comment: I have been doing that in the line : awk '{if (std) print $2-$mean/$std}' ABC_splicedavg.txt" > ABC.tmp

Comment: `$mean` or `$std` aren't what you think they are in the script.  They are not defined within single quotes.  You need to pass them to `awk` with `-v mean=${mean} ..` and use without the dollar prefix in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the precision of your output with bc by using the `scale` variable:

```
$ echo "4/7" | bc -l
.57142857142857142857
$ echo "scale=3; 4/7" | bc -l
.571
```